# Where does the energy when a photon hits an electron but the electron doesn't doesn't gain enough energy to change level?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, photons, electrons, energy-conservation

Sorry if my question is a little wordy. I was wondering the energy given by a photon goes if the electron it collides with doesn't gain enough energy to move up an energy level?

Comment: Well then, the photon didn't actually hit the electron.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm in my first year of A-Level physics so you may have to bear with me? Would you mind explaining in a bit more detail on how that'd work? Or could you link me to a resource that does?

Comment: In quantum mechanics, you have an 'overlap' of an initial state, the interaction, and a final state. If the interaction does not provide for the energy to get an electron into a different final state, your only allowed interaction is the electron ending up just where it started, which is equivalent to nothing having happened.